# Orion context broker - Limitations on attribute value and metadata values fields

Tags: fiware-orion

Are there any known limitations on the length of values of an attribute or a metadata value?

1. On setting a quite long string (>30-40k chars) at attribute value I am receiving a  jsonRequest.cpp[191]: LM ERROR: LINE TOO LONG
2. On trying to split the attribute value to several metadata values of length 1000 the exception remains the same.

version
0.25.0 (git version: a8cf800d4e9fdd7b4293a886490c40309a5bb58c)

Comment: Just to check if I'm understand correctly... Orion prints that message in the traces but continues to work correctly? Is that the situation? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. its keeps going. Here is the used payload http://pastebin.com/Pjd2hs9P and here is a sample of the console output http://pastebin.com/4PWKtQkP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an actual problem but a feature of the Orion logging subsystem to avoid printing excesively long traces.

The default limit (from [logMsg.cpp](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/src/lib/logMsg/logMsg.cpp)) is 32 Kbytes:

```
#define LINE_MAX         (32 * 1024)
```

If you want to set a higher limit (taking into account that it could "stress" logging subsystem and make your log files very big) you have to change that LINE_MAX in the source code and recompile Orion ([this document](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/admin/build_source/) details how to build from sources).

Comment: The client is getting an error response {
"errorCode": {
"code": "400"
"reasonPhrase": "Bad Request"
"details": "JSON Parse Error"
}-
}  Thanks!!

Comment: I understand that this is a separate issue (the present one is about LINE TOO LONG in the log file, the new one is about parse errors). In order not mixing new topics with old ones, could you create a new SOF question about that specific problem? Please include the exact request (verb + url + headers + payload) that is causing the problem in such new post. Thanks!